# django sort query result by occurrence count

Tags: django, sorting

I've got the flowing two models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 32)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique = True)

    ItemList = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name = "user_itemlist")
```

For Item X I want to get a list of Item objects present in ItemList for all Profile objects that contain X in ItemList, sorted by how many times each object appears.

The best I can do so far is:

```
Item.objects.filter(user_itemlist__in = User.objects.filter(profile__ItemList = X))
```

and this returns the list of all Item objects I need, with duplicates (if Item Z is present in ItemList for 10 Profile objects it will appear 10 times in the query result).

How can I sort the result of the above query by the number of times each object appears in the result and remove duplicates? Is there any "django" way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
profiles = Profile.objects.filter(profile__ItemList=X)

Item.objects.filter(
    user_itemlist__in=profiles
).annotate(itemcount=Count('id')).order_by('-itemcount')
```

Answer (score 3):

if you're using django 1.0+ you can do this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
# note that 'profile' is an instance of Profile, not the model itself
sorted_items = profile.ItemList.annotate(itemcount=Count('name'))
sorted_items = sorted_items.order_by('-itemcount')

#number of occurences of top item
sorted_items[0].itemcount
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I don't think the syntax is correct:


AttributeError: 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'annotate'

Comment: I think I have the solution, inspired by your answer, not sure yet: Item.objects.filter(user_itemlist__in = User.objects.filter(profile__ItemList = X)).annotate(itemcount=Count('id')).order_by('-itemcount')

Comment: that error means that you were using Profile (the class with a capitol 'P') instead of profile (and instance of the class)

Comment: yes I see, anyway your query sorts only the items from one profile, not exactly what I was looking for, thanks anyway your answer was helpful.